# Sort documents in solr by attr_stream_size

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I installed solr-8.3.1 locally.

Using the files-example, I prepared a solr-core using the post-utility. 
The querying of the index is very fast, now I would like to use some attributes returned when files are searched, which seem to be created during the upload.
For instance, I would like to sort by attr_stream_size.

Is there a way, to achieve that?

If I use the field directly in the query-dialog of the solr-admin:

[image: sorting by attr_stream_size]

```
"metadata":[
  "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
  "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
"msg":"can not sort on multivalued field: attr_stream_size of type: text_general",
"code":400}}
```

is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is pretty clear :

> "can not sort on multivalued field: attr_stream_size of type: text_general"

The field on which you should apply sort must be simple valued, non-tokenized and uses an analyzer that produces only a single term, or define the field type as a *string* instead of *text_general*.

The [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter) says :

> If you want to be able to sort on a field whose contents you want to
>   tokenize to facilitate searching, use a [copyField directive](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/copying-fields.html#copying-fields) in the
>   Schema to clone the field. Then search on the field and sort on its
>   clone.

For example, using a proper fieldType (ie. string or numeric field or text that uses a KeywordTokenizer or by creating a new one) specicifically for sorting, like using *plong* fieldType :

```
<field name="size" type="plong" uninvertible="true" default="0" sortMissingLast="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

the sortable field can be feed by the searchable one :

```
<copyField source="attr_stream_size" dest="size" />
```

so that you can sort by *size* while searching for *attr_stream_size*.

Comment: Thank you, the answer generally helped: I tried to do that using the admin (change the core-schema), but that did not work. After that following the hints of the admin-GUI,  I first had to create a field resulting in: <field name="size" type="plong" uninvertible="true" default="0" sortMissingLast="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/> afterwards a copyField, resulting in: 
 <copyField source="attr_stream_size" dest="size"/>. If you like, you can comment this, adapt your answer, otherwise I would describe the working solution in a separate answer.

Comment: Great ! I adapted the answer accordingly. Thanks